# Find a control on a page with a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol, master-pages

I have to find a `Control` in an aspx page bound to a master page.

The master page contains:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
```

The content page contains:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

I added a `Table` with `ID` `formtable` as a child of `Content2`.

I tried to use the following code to access the `Table`, but the code returns `null`:

```
protected void Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table tblForm = this.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("formtable") as Table;                 
}
```

How can I access the `Table`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this

```
Table tblForm = this.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("formtable") as Table;
```

Checkout this [Control ID Naming in Content Pages](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs) for more details

Answer (score 1):

What context are you in when you are trying to do this?  Are you in the codebehind of the individual page?

If you are it should be `Content1.FindControl("formtable") as Table` and that would be it.

Answer (score 1):

Working with findControl() cause complications sometimes.
It is easier to define a public property for that control in master page and then access control through the property.

you should add this line in child page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```